# Arguments in a method request a constant from an Enum - How can these methods only accept specific constants?

Tags: java, class, enums, constants

I was gonna make you all 'decipher' my code and help me solve my problem but then I realized y'all like it as plain and clear as possible so here we go (lol)...

I have the following java files:

- An Enum with multiple and every constant acting as a 'property setting' for loading a program or performing a task for that program
- A regular old class with methods and variables
- Some methods that request other methods
- Methods that can be referenced that have arguments which support *specific* constants from the Enum.

**Preview of the Enum**

```
enum Properties {

    SETTING_ENABLE_CONSOLE,
    SETTING_ENABLE_GUI,

    TASK_SCANNER_CONSOLE,
    TASK_SCANNER_GUI,

}
```

**Preview of the regular old class** - *Contains the above methods as-well*

```
class RegularClass {

/* THESE ARE THE METHODS THAT ONLY TAKE SPECIFIED CONSTANTS FROM PROPERTIES AS DEFINED BY THE METHOD. */

    static void setSetting (Properties SETTING_) { /* SET A PROPERTY!!! */ }
    static void startTask (Properties TASK_ { /* START A TASK... */ }

    static void loadProgram () {

/* THESE ARE THE METHODS THAT ARE ONLY ABLE TO PROVIDE SPECIFIC CONSTANTS FROM PROPERTIES. */

        RegularClass.setSetting(Properties.SETTING_ENABLE_CONSOLE);
        RegularClass.startTask(Properties.TASK_SCANNER_CONSOLE);
    }

}
```

### THE BIG QUESTION

How can I construct `setSetting(SETTING_)` and `startTask(TASK_)` to only take constants from

Properties enum that start with prefix provided in the argument of the method `SETTING_` and

`TASK_` without the method needing to run? (the ide such as eclipse or idea)...

In the best way possible, how can I achieve this system? Preferably I would like to utilize a *new method* that expects a result as defined by the arguments needed - but before performing the task or applying the setting. (ie; When the coder references a method such as `setSetting(SETTING_)` in a class somewhere else or even the same location.)

By full disclosure  I don't just copy and paste, I like to make my own version of it. If it's so great and simple I just might though... so you're aware. With that being said I do request you keep it simple, keep it plain and clear and don't make it so tight I cant improve from it! (I'm testing my knowledge with this as-well)

THANKS FOR YOUR TIME I DO APPRECIATE IT.

Comment: on a side note I'm really stubborn about keeping a single enum class... the grand scheme of this project is bigger than it seems and I am really hooked on keeping small things together and big things organized within their own space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. Certainly you could add some runtime input validation, but that won't add any compile time restraints. You really should split up your enums. Even if you threw an exception on invalid input, I think most users/maintainers would find it quite surprising or at least slightly irritating. It could possibly be considered a violation of the `principle of least astonishment` and quite likely the `single responsibility principle`.

There is no good reason to keep these constants in the same `enum`.

Comment: Thanks very much! I am so glad you mentioned those principles it really changes my perspective on some things. I've more or less followed the principle looking back throughout my overall project which is beneficial. It's so great because those principles demolish the goal and present a better, more efficient alternative.

Comment: I have chosen to change the overall format of the packages and classes within 'package properties.EnumClass' to package properties.singleresponsibility.EnumClass'. If I am correct that should improve encapsulation as mentioned in the single responsibility principle.

Comment: To conclude I think it's really important that you don't get to far before you really start producing results... You just might not be aware that your methods of production may not be following basic principles which especially translate to performance in sales of the finished product according to everything that just makes sense. haha